Overlapping 2 raster data
I have a raster file which a vegetation indices file where a certain indices value say: 0.2-0.4 is represented in Green Color and rest in white as shown:

I now want to overlap slope for my study area as shown:

I want to overlap vegetation indices map with slope map so that I can represent indices area with slope value and calculate area accordingly.
Is there any technique to do it???

You could make the white = no color and use transparency but your colors are too close, perhaps make your veg bright pink (Ginger Pink) and use 60% transparent. I notice that your raster does not straddle your boundary, is this intentional? Normally I'd go 10 cells extra and use masking to hide the outside cells if you don't want to see them... just saying.

The raster doesn't straddle because of pixel size out of the boundary. Can you just make me clear how can one go with 10 cells extra ? Does your idea help to calculate the area of slope as I questioned above?

Buffer the boundary by the cell width x 10 when clipping/extracting your reference data.

I tried making white color as no color, but this doesn't gives a single raster showing area for slope for vegetation indices (0.2-0.4) i.e. green color above.

I think I know what you're trying to achieve, you want to clip your slope with your indices not just to create a visual product. If you have a spatial analyst license use reclassify on your vegetation with a remaprange [[0.2,0.4,1]] and leave outside values blank, perform an extract by mask using the classified raster to isolate the slopes from there you can generate your metrics, not sure what metrics you're after so I can't advise whether to polygonize or cell statistics but that should get you fairly close.
